# How to associate clickable word with TextWatcher in EditText in android?

Tags: android, string, textwatcher, clickablespan

I have a string in android :

```
String meow =  "this_is_part1_and_here_another_and_another_one";
```

I made each word clickable using `Clickable` span.

Following is the code for implementing clickable span for each word (adapted from one of Stack Overflow answers)

```
    String meow =  "this_is_part1_and_here_another_and_another_one";
    String[] tokens = meow.split("_");

    ArrayList<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens));


    if (meow != null || meow.length() != 0  ) {
        _field.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        _field.setText(addClickablePart(meow, tokenList), EditText.BufferType.SPANNABLE);


    //  _field.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    //
    //  @Override
    //  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //  Editable ab = new SpannableStringBuilder(s.toString().replace("A", "a"));
    //  _field.setText(ab);
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // 
    //      }
    //
    //  @Override
    //  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    //        }
    //
    //  @Override
    //  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //
    //       }
    //       });

}



private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str, ArrayList<String> clickableWords) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

    for (String clickableWord : clickableWords) {
        int idx1 = str.indexOf(clickableWord);
        int idx2 = 0;
        while (idx1 != -1) {
            idx2 = idx1 + clickableWord.length();
            final String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);
            ssb.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(clickString), idx1, idx2, 0);
            idx1 = str.indexOf(clickableWord, idx2);
        }
    }

    return ssb;
}



class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {



String clicked;
public MyClickableSpan(String string) {
    super();
    clicked = string;
   }

public void onClick(View widget) {
    Toast.makeText(widget.getContext(), clicked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
    ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
   }

}
```

When I tap a particular word, I show a toast of that word. Now, what I want is when I tap that particular word, after showing that word for few seconds, that word will become blank in EditText, and I type a new word in its place, and get that particular string.

E.g  The following is shown in `EditText`:

> this_is_part1_and_here_another_and_another_one

I tap on word `part1`. After showing `part1` in toast for few seconds, the word becomes blank in EditText like this:

> this_is_ _and_here_another_and_another_one

Now I type a new word in its place say `woof`

> this_is_woof_and_here_another_and_another_one

And I get to store word `woof` in a string.

How to do that? In short, how do I make my clickable words associate with TextWatcher? I commented the TextWatcher part as I don't know how to associate it with ClickableSpan. Please help me in this. Thanks.

Comment: What string to store the word `woof`?

Comment: It's just an example. I want to store all the previous clickable words and all the edited words in that word's place in a map/multimap

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "hyperlink" different words in a span. You just get the text view's on click listener. I'd suggest you build a `ViewGroup` that encapsulates one or more words and can respond to individual word clicks,

```
class HyperText extends LinearLayout {
  ...
  public static interface OnTextClickedListener {
    public void onTextClicked(String text);
  }   


  public void addText(String text) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(...); // or inflate it from somewhere
    tx.setOnClickListener(...); // call onTextClicked(this.getText());
    addView(tv);
  }
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: No, I am creating spans for each individual word. I just need a mechanism to tap on a word, then replace that word by typing and retrieve the typed word .

Comment: Yes, see above. There's nothing in Android that's going to do that for you. You need to write the code yourself.